# error in python d not defined.

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning python and have this error . I can figure out where\what the error is in the code.
`File "<string>", line 1, in <module>`.

```
Name = ""
Desc = ""
Gender = ""
Race = ""
# Prompt user for user-defined information
Name = input('What is your Name? ')
Desc = input('Describe yourself: ')
```

When i run the program

it outputs
What is your Name?  (i input d )

this gives the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/python/chargen.py", line 19, in <module>
    Name = input('What is your Name? ')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'd' is not defined
```

This is an example code from Python 3 for Absolute Beginners.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Python 2.x, `input()` expects something which is a Python expression, which means that if you type `d` it interprets that as a *variable* named d. If you typed `"d"`, then it would be fine.

What you probably actually want for 2.x is `raw_input()`, which returns the entered value as a raw string instead of evaluating it.

Since you're getting this behavior, it looks like you're using a 2.x version of the Python interpreter - instead, I'd go to [www.python.org](http://www.python.org) and download a Python 3.x interpreter so that it will match up with the book you're using.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably using Python 2.x, where `input` will `eval` the user input. Only in Python 3.x `input()` returns the raw user input.

You can check the version of Python by running `python` in console, e.g. this is Python 2.6:

```
~$ python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr  5 2010, 00:18:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5659)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

You can run a specific version of Python (e.g. 3.1) by `python3.1`:

```
~$ python3.1
Python 3.1.1 (r311:74480, Jan 25 2010, 15:23:53) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646) (dot 1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: Hi kennyTM

thanks a lot ! yup it looks like a version conflict :(

Python 2.6.4 (r264:75706, Dec  7 2009, 18:45:15) 
[GCC 4.4.1] on linux2

will upgrade my python version. I would never have figured it out without you guys thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.0 and above, which the book you are using teaches, `input()` does what `raw_input()` did in Python 2, so in that case the code would be correct; however, it appears that you are using an older version of Python (2.6?).

I would recommend going to the [Python website](http://www.python.org) and downloading the latest version of Python 3 instead, so you have an easier time following the book.

---

The immediate problem, given that you are using Python 2, is that you're using `input()`, which evaluates whatever you give it. What you want to do is get the raw string that the user input:

```
Name = raw_input("What is your Name? ")
```

There are lots of little differences between Python 3.x and 2.x, so definitely go get the latest Python 3 if you want to keep using *Python 3 for Absolute Beginners*.