# python says variable name is a syntax error

Tags: python

Every time I try to run these first 2 lines in python, it says:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And highlights the name of the variable I'm trying to define (`Yname`).

These are the lines I'm trying to run:

```
print("Hello what's your name?")\       
Yname = input("your name:")
```

Comment: Why do you have the backslash in there?  Just take it out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [error in python d not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612948/error-in-python-d-not-defined)

Comment: remove '\' from first line

Comment: @AamirAdnan Because he's getting a `SyntaxError`, not a `NameError`, I don't think this problem is a dupe of that (though he may very well run into that error soon). However, this question should still be closed as Off-topic/typographical error.

Comment: @dano there was an empty line in between two line of code and the line continuation '\' was not the problem until @sharth edited it so before I thought the OP might having `NameError`.

Comment: "SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement" I took out the backslash and then got this, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

It is because of the `\` at the end of the first line.
in Python `\` is the line continuation character. Python is trying to parse this as

```
print("Hello what's your name?")Yname = input("your name:")
```

Comment: +1 -- I think that showing it this way (as python is trying to parse it) also nicely demonstrates _why_ the `SyntaxError` pointed at `Yname` when really the problem exists on the previous line to the human eye.