# If Input Equals Strings Do (Something) Not Working Python 3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, input

I've recently been creating a text adventure game but almost immediately ran into a problem with the input. It is giving me error messages when I use strings instead of integers. There is probably an obvious reason that this is happening and I'm just not seeing it.

Here's an example:

```
    b = input("Do you like video games? y/n")
    if b == "y":
        print("Good For You!")
    if b == "n":
        print("What!? (Just joking)")
```

I've researched a lot and this seems to be working for most other people. But when I use it I get this error:

```
    Do you like video games? y/ny
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/Test.py", line 1, in <module>
        b = input("Do you like video games? y/n")
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

As you can see, it says that y is not defined. I'm okay with basic python programming, but I'm horrible at reading error messages. It would be great if you guys could give me an answer. Thank you!

Comment: You're not on Python 3 like you think you are.

Comment: Are you sure you're using Python 3? For me, that error only appears if I run your code in Python 2.

Comment: If you try to run your code on linux make sure you use `python3 Test.py` to run it from terminal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NameError from Python input() function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16457441/nameerror-from-python-input-function) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122540/python-input-error-nameerror-name-is-not-defined) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413502/nameerror-name-n-is-not-defined-even-though-its-an-input-python) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612948/error-in-python-d-not-defined)...

Answer (score 0):

That error from using the `input` function is typical of Python 2 and not Python 3. I suspect you are actually using Python 2.

To determine which version of python runs when you use the `python` command:

```
$ python --version
# example output: Python 2.7.3
```

To make sure you run your script using python 3, do:

```
$ python3 scriptname.py
```

## Python 2

In Python 2, to get user input, you actually need to use the function [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input), as the [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) function tries to evaluate the user's input as if it were python code.

So when the user inputs `'y'`, the `input` function then tries to evaluate the *expression* `y`, which in this case would mean the *variable* named `y`, which doesn't exist.

So for python 2, your code should look like:

```
b = raw_input("Do you like video games? y/n")
# etc
```

## Python 3

In python 3, the [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function takes the place of `raw_input`, so your code would work as-is.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually using Python 2, not 3 unfortunately. Since you are using `input()` in Python *2*, `input()` actually is evaluating the expression, instead of being Python 3's equivalent for Python 2's `raw_input()`. `input()` in this case, failed to find a variable with the name `y` (the input) and raised the error.

Simply change your Python version from 2.x to 3.x and you should be fine. If you are sticking with Python 2 though, use `raw_input()` instead:

```
b = raw_input("Do you like video games? y/n")
```