# small program stops - why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

Whats wrong with my code? 
After the second "input" the program stops...

```
convr = 0

x = input("Inform value: ")
y = input("Inform if is Dolar (D) or Euro (E): ")

convt = x * convr

if y == "D":
    convr = 1/0.895
    print (convt)
elif y == "E":
    convr = 0.895
    print (convt)
else:
    print ("NOT ALLOWED!")
```

Comment: Check this. It may be relevant in your case. I complied your piece of code in python fiddle and I get named error as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612948/error-in-python-d-not-defined

Comment: I solved the problem of "convt". But now i dont know a way to multiply the input (that is a string) with a float.

Comment: Use Google, and search for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your `x` variable is a string, you need to transform it to number, eg. `float` or `int`.

```
x = float(input("Inform value: "))
y = input("Inform if is Dolar (D) or Euro (E): ")

if y == "D":
    convr = 1/0.895
    convt = x * convr
    print (convt)
elif y == "E":
    convr = 0.895
    convt = x * convr
    print (convt)
else:
    print ("NOT ALLOWED!")
---------
# Inform value: 2345
# Inform if is Dolar (D) or Euro (E): D
# 2620.1117318435754
```

Comment: U helped me a lot! Thx! :D

Answer (score 0):

The program doesn's stop. Just your value is empty.
You can see what I mean by changing your print() statements to:

```
print ('RESULT: ' + convt)
```

Now, instead of a blank line, you will get "Result: " printed to the screen.

The reason you don't get a value is because of this line:

```
convt = x * convr
```

When you run this convr is equal to zero. Any number times by zero equals zero. :)